# How to run multiple Lua scripts within the same lua state without conflict

Tags: lua

I've been working with Lua for sometime and there is a problem that I could never solve it. First, I'm using a single lua state to have a connection between my scripts so they could transfer data via global table `_G`.

My scripts have a template like this:

```
-- Vars
local somevar = 0

-- Update
function Update()
  -- stuff
end
```

I call `Update()` function from my application every game step, but since there are other scripts loaded in current lua state with the same template only the `Update()` function from the last chunk in lua is getting called and there is no way I can call all of `Update()` functions in my scripts.

If I load my scripts every time I want to call the functions, It'll work the way I want, but this way my local variables and every change that I have made to the scripts would get dumped because the chunk is replaced with a new one.

I've seen a message on Lua's site itself which talks about setting an environment for each chunk that is going to get loaded, but that's not what I want because it forces each script to reside in a unique table and there is no way to communicate with global table since we're going to override the global table for our unique tables.

I'd really appreciate if someone give me some advice because there isn't really much on the internet about these kinds of stuff.

**UPDATE**

I know the answer to first part of my question. Right now I'm using a table for each of my scripts, something like this:

*code1.lua*

```
code1 = {}

function code1.Update()
  -- Update
end
```

This makes every script accessible via the global table with their table name. The problem is if I load this script for another object in my game, then it'll conflict with the previously loaded script because they're both using the same source and therefore the same names and I can only access the last loaded. As you can see, I've stated this about environments in first part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I solved it with event system

```
local __events = {}
function addEventListener(event, callback)
    local listeners = __events[event]
    if listeners ~= nil then
        listeners[#listeners + 1] = callback
    else
        __events[event] = {callback}
    end
end

function trigger(event, ...)
    local listeners = __events[event]
    if listeners ~= nil then
        for i = 1, #listeners do
            listeners[i](...)
        end
    end
end
```

Add event listener function saves callback function into table with array
of functions for each event. Trigger function find array of functions for event
and call all of them. For each event C code will call I create one function which
just call trigger("EventName")

```
function event_update(elapsed)
    trigger("update", elapsed)
end
```

And all other scripts use

```
addEventListener("update", function(elapsed)

end)
```

Comment: I guess a downside of this method is that you can't easily trigger a single update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use environments and communicate using the global table using metatables, which will allow the local environment to inherit the global one.
With Lua 5.2:

```
function loadEnv(file)
    local newenv = {}
    setmetatable(newenv, { __index=_G })
    loadfile(file, "bt", newenv)()
    return newenv
end
globalVar = "Global"
newenv1 = loadEnv("update1.lua")
newenv2 = loadEnv("update2.lua")

newenv1.Update()
newenv2.Update()
```

With the scripts:

```
-- update1.lua
local somevar = 0
print(_ENV)
function Update()
    print("update1")
    print(somevar)
    print(globalVar)
    _G.globalVar = "global2" -- use this to create/modify a global variable
end
```

And

```
-- update2.lua
local somevar = 1
print(_ENV)
function Update()
    print("update2")
    print(somevar)
    print(globalVar)
end
```

You'll get:

```
table: 0044ED78
table: 009C9AC0
update1
0
Global
update2
1
global2
```

Comment: Well I intended to do that, but I did it another way. I'm using a unique table for each script which is pretty similar to this method, but the problem with this is whenever I create two objects which have two scripts with the same source, there would be this whole thing again because I can't choose a unique name for every runtime created object.

Comment: You can run the scripts as many times as you want, and they will remain independent as they will have their own private environment. This is because the environment is set externally, and not in the script itself. The table returned by loadEnv represents the object.

Comment: I think I'm not clear enough. For example, `newenv1` and `newenv2` are written by us which means we've written them with further information about the code. What I say is, I create real game objects in C++ which they have a script list to run. When I create instances from these objects at runtime I can't choose a unique environment name for each of the newly created scripts, therefore I don't have any access to them after that. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: You might want to edit the question then, to add clarity, and describe the solution you went with.

Comment: I'm afraid that makes it two questions in a row. That's why I tended to ask one. I'll add extra information.

Comment: If you need unique names, are you ok with arbitrary names? If so, you can use an empty table as an index, then fill that entry for the table, whilst the object calling the code just needs to keep a reference to that particular empty table.

Comment: @Dave Naming is the first problem. Imagine I want to create bullet objects and every bullet has an script attached to it, how I'm going to access their scripts? Well I suppose I'm going to set a unique table name for each one and then what? I don't want access them with a weird name like `bullet_...` which I don't even like.

Comment: Add the script functions to an entry in table called bullets, you can use pairs to iterate the values to perform checks, and your loop variables will have both the identifier and the actual bullet table.

Comment: Almost @ 1000, +1 ;-)